# How to use alternate icons in Office UI Fabric React

Tags: office-ui-fabric

The Office UI Fabric license only allows use of the icons in Office Apps. I'd like to substitute alternative icons but I'm not sure how to do it.

Specifically, I'd like to override the icons in the `MessageBar` component i.e. the  icon on the left and the X on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `registerIcons` to register new icons e.g. Here's how to do it with font awesome to register icons for a blocked `MessageBar`:

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import {
    faExclamationCircle,
    faTimes
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { registerIcons } from "@uifabric/styling";

library.add(faExclamationCircle);
library.add(faTimes);

registerIcons({
    icons: {
        blocked2: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />,
        clear: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
    }
});
```